# Flutter : How to change listtile color in ListView Builder , from list of colors. Even list of colors size is less than items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Suppose list of colors are ,

List colors = [Colors.red, Colors.yellow,Colors.blue, Colors.green]; //4 colors
and items are more than 4 , how do I repeat these colors for next items.

[image: pic]

Expected result,

item1 - red,
item2 - yellow,
item3 - blue,
item4 - green,
item5 - red,
item6 - yellow,
item7 - blue,
item8 - green,

[image: pic2]

Full Code

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


  void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }

  List colors = [Colors.red, Colors.yellow,Colors.blue, Colors.green];

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: MyWidget(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 8,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
            return ListTile(
                tileColor: colors[index] ,
              
              title:Text("List item $index")
              );
          }
          );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is working code:
[image]

If you want a infinite list, set itemCount to null :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable that you can reference for the index from the color list.

```
int i = 0;
```

Then, on your ListView.builder builder function, check if you reached the end of the list.

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: 8,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){

   if (i > colors.length) i = 0;

   final color = colors[i];
   i++;
   return ListTile(
     tileColor: color, 
     title:Text("List item $index")
   );
   
   }
 )
```

I do not know if this is efficient but you get the idea.

Comment: final color = colors[index % colors.length]

Answer (score 1):

you can resize your color array:

```
colorsArray.removeRange(itemNameList.length, colorsArray.length);
```